# ClearCase: Creating baseline in snapshot view

Tags: clearcase

with ClearCase UCM I can create a baseline in a snapshot view directory. When not all files are up-to-date, which version of a file is included in the baseline?

Example: version 3 of foo.txt is located in the snapshot view directory and there already exists a version 4 of this file. Which version of the file is referenced by the baseline?

Does this depends on the version of ClearCase (I am using ClearCase 7.1)? Do I have to consider something?

Background of the question: for a continuous integration build I want to use a snapshot view. When during creating or updating the snapshot view an other user checks in a file to the same stream this new version may or may not be part of the snapshot. At least I want be to be able to identify which files in my snapshot directory have been used by the build.

Answer (score 2):

[About Baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346788/difference-between-baseline-and-benchmark-in-performance-of-an-application/346835#346835): A [`mkbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm) depends on the selection mechanism (the config spec)
of the local access mechanism (snapshot or dynamic view) providing said selection mechanism.

> For each element in the component, the baseline records the version of that element selected by the stream's configuration at the time `mkbl` is executed.

So the `-view` parameter is only there to reference the Stream (and its associated config spec):

```
-vie/w view-tag
```

> Specifies the view from which to create baselines. Baselines are created in the stream that the view is attached to.
>
> For example, if you are working in `coyne_dev_view`, but want to create a baseline from the configuration specified by the view `coyne_integration_view`, use `-view coyne_integration_view`.
>   This option creates a baseline in the project's integration stream that includes all the checked-in versions contained in `coyne_integration_view`.
>   If you do not specify view-tag, the current view is used.

In your case, if your UCM view is supposed to select `v4`, but is currently selecting `v3` because that snapshot view hasn't been updated yet, the baseline should reference `v3` (what is currently selected by the view).

So for your background question, best to perform a `cleartool update` before the `mkbl`.